# Integrating Django and openui5

Tags: django, sapui5

I want to use openui5 with django applications. There is no information about it. It's unclear how to use ui5 routing with django urls.py. Perhaps someone has to experience this?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing front-end routing with back-end routing.
OpenUI5 applications are designed to be [single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), so what you have to do is basically load the whole app in your `index` route and create other routes to expose the data from django, assuming you want to follow the [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) architecture.